# How to properly use EXISTS and IN in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am comparing two queries using EXISTS and IN. They both give different results. When I use the query using IN the result is the correct one but when using the EXISTS query I am getting multiple records, there should have been only 1 record.

Benchmark:
**IN Query** - 17 seconds to get the result
**EXISTS Query** - 9-11 seconds to get the result

Expected Result:
**1** - record

IN Query (1 Record):

```
SELECT CINO, CLIENTID, COID, ADDRVER, ASSETFIX, AVEMONSALE, BRCHAFFL, BUS
  DESC, BUSTYPE, CAPITAL, CONTACT, FACCOND, FIXASSET, FIXTURE, INFADDR,
  INFORMANT, INVENTORY, LANDLORD, LASTYRSALE, LIABILITY, LINEPRDSRV,
  LOTAREA, MACHINE, MAJBAN, MAKE, MOTOR, NATINC, NUMEMPLOY, OBSERVE,
  OBSERVE2, OBTINFORM, OFFCAREA, OFFCBLDG, OFFCLOC, OFFCVALUE, OFFORG,
  OTHERINC, POSITION, RECEIVABLE, REGWITH, REMARKS, REMNEG, REMPOS, RENTEXP,
  YRSOPER, YRINCOME, DATEORG, SUPPLIER 
FROM LCBINV 
WHERE CINO IN (
  SELECT CINO FROM LCMINV WHERE AUDITKY IN (
    SELECT AUDITKY 
    FROM LSAUDIT
    WHERE ENTRYDT > '03-Nov-2019' AND ENTRYTM > '07:15:10'
  )
)
```

Exist Query (200 Records):

```
SELECT CINO, CLIENTID, COID, ADDRVER, ASSETFIX, AVEMONSALE, BRCHAFFL, BUS
  DESC, BUSTYPE, CAPITAL, CONTACT, FACCOND, FIXASSET, FIXTURE, INFADDR,
  INFORMANT, INVENTORY, LANDLORD, LASTYRSALE, LIABILITY, LINEPRDSRV,
  LOTAREA, MACHINE, MAJBAN, MAKE, MOTOR, NATINC, NUMEMPLOY, OBSERVE,
  OBSERVE2, OBTINFORM, OFFCAREA, OFFCBLDG, OFFCLOC, OFFCVALUE, OFFORG,
  OTHERINC, POSITION, RECEIVABLE, REGWITH, REMARKS, REMNEG, REMPOS, 
  RENTEXP, YRSOPER, YRINCOME, DATEORG, SUPPLIER 
FROM LCBINV 
WHERE CINO IN (
  SELECT CINO FROM LCMINV WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT AUDITKY FROM LSAUDIT 
    WHERE ENTRYDT > '03-Nov-2019' AND ENTRYTM > '07:15:10'
  )
)
```

So here is my query's function, It basically check if there are updates in the individual's information if ENTRYDT and ENTRYTM is greater that the date and time last checked.

My problem is why am I getting multiple records on EXISTS query even though ENTRYDT is not greater that the date?

Comment: Most likely the second query is using the wrong columns. Please add aliases to the tables `LCMINV` and `LSAUDIT` and prepend each column with the correct alias.

Comment: @TheImpaler why do I need an alias when using a EXIST? and can you post a sample?

Comment: Not needed, except when you have correlated subqueries. Is it the case here? It's not clear from the example.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes I need to correlate the subqueries because the table LCBINV  is dependent LCMINV table to check whether there is an update

Comment: Please add aliases to all columns in the filter (`WHERE` clause).

Comment: @TheImpaler can you show my how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These queries are not similar at all.  If this is the `in` query:

```
WHERE LCBINV.CINO IN (SELECT L2.CINO
                      FROM LCMINV L2
                      WHERE L2AUDITKY IN (SELECT A.AUDITKY 
                                          FROM LSAUDIT A
                                          WHERE A.ENTRYDT > DATE '2019-11-03'AND A.ENTRYTM > '07:15:10'
                                         )
                     )
```

The equivalent query with `EXISTS` in the subquery would be:

```
WHERE LCBINV.CINO IN (SELECT L2.CINO
                      FROM LCMINV L2
                      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM LSAUDIT A
                                    WHERE A.AUDITKY = L2.AUDITKY AND
                                          A.ENTRYDT > DATE '2019-11-03' AND
                                          A.ENTRYTM > '07:15:10'
                                   )
                     )
```

In other words, you are missing the correlation clause.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it.

Comment: @TheImpaler I used the answer It takes so long to get the result

Comment: @MarkStewart if you compare the result time when I'm using the IN query and the posted answers is very different its correct but the cost of performance

Comment: @Blank317 . . . This answers the question of why your two queries return different result sets.  If you have a question about performance, ask a *new* question and provide some information about the tables, existing indexes, the number of rows returned by the query . . .